# FFMPEG build still resulting in `Illegal instruction` on raspberry pi ZERO, but not PI 2+

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

The process in which I do it configures the lib and ffmpeg files on the zero then move over to a pi 3 to make and install it (for speed).

Build process:

```
# x264
git clone git://git.videolan.org/x264.git
cd x264
sudo ./configure --host=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi --enable-shared --disable-opencl
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig

# FFMPEG
git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git
cd ffmpeg
sudo ./configure --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
sudo make
sudo make install
```

I tried following this [cross compile type build](https://gist.github.com/daz/0fecfb80dca969c0a3b4) but complained I was missing a C compiler, but GCC was installed. SO I just went to follow my previous method.

Results of trying to run it:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
ffmpeg version N-85747-gc4be288 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 61.100 / 55. 61.100
  libavcodec     57. 93.100 / 57. 93.100
  libavformat    57. 72.101 / 57. 72.101
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 88.100 /  6. 88.100
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 682.500534, bitrate: 110592 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x360, 110592 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
[tcp @ 0x2cba570] Connection to tcp://localhost:8090 failed (Connection refused), trying next address
Wed May  3 12:30:16 2017 127.0.0.1 - - [GET] "/feed1.ffm HTTP/1.1" 200 4175
[tcp @ 0x2cbf1b0] Connection to tcp://localhost:8090 failed (Connection refused), trying next address
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
No pixel format specified, yuv422p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
Wed May  3 12:30:16 2017 127.0.0.1 - - [POST] "/feed1.ffm HTTP/1.1" 200 0
Illegal instruction
```